# what event listener to add to radio button when page is swiped in Android?

Tags: android-widget, android, android-button

[image: pageController]

I am working on a page controller application. My logic involves placing custom radio buttons at the bottom of one page.

I would like to create a listener on the radio button when the user swipes the page to move to the next. I am not aware exactly how to do this. I have attached an image to relay my idea.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[See this example](http://viewpagerindicator.com/)

You have to just go through this example.Its has different type of TabIndicator.So read it and play with it. Hope it help you